# Laravel Model save() & update() Not Saving

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

**Laravel 5.7**

Hello I have been looking through stack overflow and have tried many possible answers and have come to no conclusions.

I am updating a simple integer value in a patron table through simple checks and it is not updating the database. I have tried using `save()` and `update()` methods on the model.

There are no errors or exceptions that show up and the `save()` and `update()` methods return `true`.

code:

Controller Class Using the model and updating data:

```php
$patron_coupon = PatronCoupons::where('owner',$patron_id)->where('coupon_id',$active_coupon['coupon_id'])->first();

if($patron_coupon->current_uses > $active_coupon['max_uses'])
    $patron_coupon->current_uses = $active_coupon['max_uses'];
// if i echo $patron_coupon->current_uses here, it will show that this value has changed ( good )

$patron_coupon->current_uses = $active_coupon['max_uses'] - $patron_coupon->times_used;
if($patron_coupon->current_uses < 0)
    $patron_coupon->current_uses = 0;

// this doesnt work 
$patron_coupon->save();
// this doesnt work either 
$patron_coupon->update($patron_coupon->toArray());
// if i echo current_uses here, the value goes back to what it was before being set.
```

Model Class:

```php
class PatronCoupons extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'patron_coupons';
    protected $primaryKey = 'owner';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = ['times_used','current_uses','settings_version'];
}
```

Migration File:

```php
Schema::create('patron_coupons', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->string('owner');                                // patron id that 'owns' this coupon
    $table->unsignedInteger('coupon_id');                   // id of this coupon
    $table->unsignedInteger('current_uses')->default(0);    // the amount of uses this patron has for this coupon
    $table->unsignedInteger('settings_version')->nullable();// last settings version fetch
    $table->unsignedInteger('times_used')->default(0);      // amount of times this coupon has been used
});
```

Please help, I've been banging my head on my desk for **hours** !!!!!

Comment: if you set the value outside the if are you getting anything?

`
$patron_coupon->current_uses = 20;
$patron_coupon->save();
`

Comment: Thanks for the response @PhxSteve. Just tried that and still no change in the database! I have no idea what's going on

Comment: Can you also add a dd($patron_coupon->current_users);  Ideally you get 20.  Other thing I would be curious is if you manually change the db value of current uses and dump the value after you retrieve it.  To make sure its getting correct value from the db

Comment: Try updating using static function instead `update([ 'current_uses' => 12 ])`?

Comment: @JonathanK **That works and updates the database as it should. ** I can use this as a viable solution for now, but why is that working and not just `save()`?

Comment: @PhxSteve The value before `save()` gets set correctly if I echo the value EXCEPT that when I fire `save()`, it goes back to what it was before.

Comment: Happy it worked. I can't really tell why it's not working. You could always remove your `vendor` and `composer.lock` file and run `composer install` again. Might work

Comment: @JonathanK just tried that and ran `composer install`, still did not work with my original code. I'm going to stick with the static function instead, it's all I really need. Thanks yall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try any of the following:

1. Try using static `update` function instead

   ```
   PatronCoupons::update([
       // updates here
   ]);
   ```
2. Remove your `vendor` folder and `composer.lock` file. Then run `composer install` to refresh your vendor file

Answer (score 1):

get record

```
$patronCoupons = PatronCoupons::find($id);

$patronCoupons->update([
    'times_used' => 'value',
    'current_uses' => 'value',
    'settings_version' => 'value'
]);
```

if your post data with the same input name then directly use

```
$post = $request->all();

$patronCoupons = PatronCoupons::find($id);

$patronCoupons->update($post);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you put this code in the form because of which the error occurs

```
'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
```